# NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier throwing error on ios 7

Tags: ios, nscalendar

I am creating my app with Xcode 6 and it works fine on ios8. I just tested the app on ios7 and i get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3a78418c
```

This is the code i am using as part of converting dates from Gregorian calendar to Persian Calendar:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:@"persian"];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `+[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier]` class method is only available on iOS 8/OS X 10.9 and later.

But you can use the designated initializer method instead, this works on all iOS releases:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:@"persian"];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to work from iOS 8.

```
+ (NSCalendar *)calendarWithIdentifier:(NSString *)calendarIdentifierConstant NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
```